# Webpack file naming convention

Tags: webpack, symfony4

Webpack builds css and js files with a hash.

```
5 files written to public\build
Entrypoint app = runtime.d2591ff7.js 0.146fc849.css 0.bdcc5dc6.js app.a97e0bd7.css app.5b254551.jsDone in 4.76s.
```

When I repeat yarn encore dev, "146fc849" is the same. How is it created?

I would actually prefer to use 0.css. How can I configure webpack to name these files without hashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hash of the file's contents - it won't change unless its contents do - and you shouldn't just use `0.css` because the point of the hash is so browsers don't serve the old, cached version of `0.css`.

See https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/ for details on how this is configured.

Comment: First of all thanks for your message. Is there a way to add this css file to the template so that even its name changes twig somehow finds it?
I will sell this script to third parties. So when they change css content, its name will be changed so the link href's will be needed to be changed.

Comment: @tolga Already handled by Encore. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/versioning.html - "Loading Assets from entrypoints.json & manifest.json" and the bit about Twig's `asset` helper.

Comment: OK but in manifest.json, "build/0.146fc849.css": "/build/0.146fc849.css". When I add 0.css in template it can't find the path. I tried to add a line to manifest.json but it's regenerated in each build. Is this possible to map like this?

Comment: @tolga You probably shouldn't be doing anything with `0.css` directly.

Comment: May be I should ask this as a seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

**ceejayoz**'s answer is the right one. I add this answer as a supportive information: If you want to disable this functionality, simply comment out enableVersioning in the webpack config:

```
// .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
```